# How do I calculate the probability P(x | z) from a Bayesian Network?

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

[image]

I have a bayesian network as illustrated above and I want to calculate probability for $P(x|z).$ I am applying the formula:

\begin{align}P(x|z) &= \sum\limits_{y} P(z, x, y)\\&= P(x) \times[P(z|x,y) \times P(y) + P(z|x,\neg y) \times P(\neg y)]\end{align}

However I'm getting the wrong answer. It seems like I'm still missing a fundamental aspect of the problem with normalization that I'm not able to comprehend. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A hint: your first equality is incorrect. Recall the difference between joint and conditional probabilities.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Ahhh. So I tried directly applying Bayes' Theorem: P(x|z) = P(z|x) * P(x) / P(z)  I surprisingly got P(z|x) * P(x) = ∑y P(z, x, y) which was the incorrect equality (assuming my derivation was even correct). How would I then calculate the marginal probability for P(z)? I tried ∑y ∑x P(z, x, y) but that didn't make sense to me and got confused.